# Save big image in another thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a small GUI showing different layers on top of a displayed image. At some point i want to store the current image with all visualized layers to disk, while continueing to work with the GUI. Images are rather large (storing takes approx. 5 seconds), so i wanted to offload the saving into a background thread.

I tried different approaches, none of them worked. Minimal working example (which still needs a PNG for testing, sorry):

```
import sys
import threading

from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QRunnable, QThreadPool
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QSizePolicy, QAction, QToolBar


class StorageQRunnable(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self,
                 pixmap: QPixmap,
                 target_path: str):
        super(StorageQRunnable, self).__init__()

        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.target_path = target_path

    def run(self):
        print("Starting to write image in QRunnable.")
        self.pixmap.save(self.target_path, "PNG")
        print("Done writing image in QRunnable.")


class StorageQThread(QThread):

    signal = pyqtSignal("PyQt_PyObject")

    def __init__(self,
                 pixmap: QPixmap,
                 target_path: str):
        super(StorageQThread, self).__init__()

        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.target_path = target_path

    def run(self):
        print("Starting to write image in QThread.")
        self.pixmap.save(self.target_path, "PNG")
        print("Done writing image in QThread.")
        self.signal.emit(0)


class StorageThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,
                 pixmap: QPixmap,
                 target_path: str):
        super(StorageThread, self).__init__()

        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.target_path = target_path

    def run(self):

        print("Starting to write image in threading.Thread.")
        self.pixmap.save(self.target_path, "PNG")
        print("Done writing image in threading.Thread.")


class TrialWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrialWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.imageLabel = QLabel()
        self.imageLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.imageLabel)

        toolbar = QToolBar("Controls")
        toolbar.addAction(QAction("Do", self, shortcut="Ctrl+F", triggered=self.continue_in_foreground))
        toolbar.addAction(QAction("To background", self, shortcut="Ctrl+B", triggered=self.to_background))
        toolbar.addAction(QAction("Exit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=self.close))
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        self.bg_task_started = False

    def continue_in_foreground(self):
        print("Doing.")

    def thread_done(self, status: int):
        if status == 0:
            print(":)")

    def to_background(self):
        print("Background.")

        if not self.bg_task_started:

            # print("I Pushing threading.Thread to background.")
            # StorageThread(pixmap=self.imageLabel.pixmap().copy(), target_path="/tmp/target1.png").start()

            # print("II Pushing QThread to background.")
            # self.w2 = StorageQThread(pixmap=self.imageLabel.pixmap().copy(), target_path="/tmp/target1.png")
            # self.w2.signal.connect(self.thread_done)
            # self.w2.start()

            print("III Pushing QRunnable to background.")
            r = StorageQRunnable(pixmap=pixmap.copy(), target_path="/tmp/target1.png")
            QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(r)

            self.bg_task_started = True

    def visualize(self, pxmp: QPixmap):

        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(pxmp)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TrialWindow()

    # load pixmap
    img = Image.open("/tmp/sample.png")
    image = ImageQt(img)
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)

    window.show()
    window.visualize(pixmap)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Short manual:**

- Start
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to see console outputs from GUI-thread (one or multiple times)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to start storing the large PNG in a background thread
- Continue pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, see that nothing happens until the image is stored and all events are processed afterwards only (GUI is unusable)
- Exit via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Feel free to comment in different approaches, i.e., the usage of `threading.Thread`, the usage of `QThread` or the usage of `QRunnable`, all with the same result: Storing the pixmap as PNG (which should actually happen in a background thread) blocks the GUI.

Comment: I know it fails because the GUI is not responding while the thread should run in the background. The program behaves the same no matter if i (try to) run the pixmap-storing in a background thread or not; the pixmap-storage call is blocking. Which i don't want.

Comment: 18MegaPixel, RGB

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/Okanagan_Lake_near_KGH_in_winter_2010-18_megapixel.jpg

This should do the trick, at least after storing it as PNG. Otherwise i have to provide a png as soon as i'm back at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the threads but QPixmap is not thread-safe and should not be manipulated from another thread as [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread) points out:

> #### GUI Thread and Worker Thread
>
> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This
>   thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in
>   Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in this thread. **All widgets and
>   several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary
>   threads**. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker
>   thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main
>   thread.

Instead you should use QImage that is optimized for I/O operation as [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#details) points out:

> Qt provides four classes for handling image data: QImage, QPixmap,
>   QBitmap and QPicture. **QImage is designed and optimized for I/O, and
>   for direct pixel access and manipulation**, while QPixmap is designed
>   and optimized for showing images on screen. QBitmap is only a
>   convenience class that inherits QPixmap, ensuring a depth of 1. The
>   isQBitmap() function returns true if a QPixmap object is really a
>   bitmap, otherwise returns false. Finally, the QPicture class is a
>   paint device that records and replays QPainter commands.

So the solution is:

```
self.imageLabel.pixmap().toImage()
```

Code:

```
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class SaveWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def save(self, image, path):
        threading.Thread(target=self._save, args=(image, path,), daemon=True).start()

    def _save(self, image, path):
        self.started.emit()
        image.save(path, "PNG")
        self.finished.emit()


class TrialWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TrialWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.imageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.imageLabel.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored
        )
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.imageLabel)

        toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar("Controls")
        toolbar.addAction(
            QtWidgets.QAction(
                "Do", self, shortcut="Ctrl+F", triggered=self.continue_in_foreground
            )
        )
        toolbar.addAction(
            QtWidgets.QAction(
                "To background", self, shortcut="Ctrl+B", triggered=self.to_background
            )
        )
        toolbar.addAction(
            QtWidgets.QAction("Exit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=self.close)
        )
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        self.worker = SaveWorker()
        self.worker.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

    def visualize(self, pxmp: QtGui.QPixmap):
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(pxmp)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def continue_in_foreground(self):
        print("Doing.")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_started(self):
        print("started")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        print("finished")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def to_background(self):
        self.worker.save(self.imageLabel.pixmap().toImage(), "/tmp/target1.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # load pixmap
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("/tmp/sample.png")

    window = TrialWindow()
    window.show()

    window.visualize(pixmap)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You.Are.My.Hero.